# Call Swift function with multiple arguments form Objective-C syntax

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, function

From Objective-C, to call a a Swift function with one argument you have to use bracket syntax and do something I've always found confusing: Add the word "With" before the argument and capitalize the argument label as in:

//swift extension

```
@objc public func getImageCalled(name: String?) -> UIImage? {
}

//Called from Objective-C
 ImageClass *imgObject = [[ImageClass alloc] init];
 UIImage * img = [imgObject getImageCalledWithName:myname];
```

How do you do this with two arguments as in:

```
@objc public func getImageCalled(name: String?,width:Int?) -> UIImage? {
}
```

`[imgObject getImageCalledWithName:myname WithWidth:30];` is not working for me.

Comment: Does your Swift code compile at all? There should be an error message “Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 2 cannot be represented in Objective-C”

Comment: Any reason why that width is optional?

Comment: The `With<NameOfFirstParameter>` is only a convention for the first argument, all subsequent arguments are just named the same. It originates from Objective-C where you don't specify a named argument for the first parameter due to its syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
[imgObject getImageCalledWithName:myname width:30];
```